# Ruby include? in an if-statement

Tags: ruby

Why does this result in a syntax error "syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end"?:

```
if "test".include?"te" || "test".include?"fail"
  puts "true"
end
```

The following works:

```
fail = "test".include?"fail"

if "test".include?"te" || fail
  puts "true"
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Another solution: replace operator "||" with "or" which has lower precedence so you can leave parentheses omitted:

```
if "test".include?"te" or "test".include?"fail"
  puts "true"
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Use parentheses with those `include?` arguments.

```
if "test".include?("te") || "test".include?("fail")
  puts "true"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You must use a brace around the 2nd parameter.

```
if "test".include?("te") || "test".include?("fail")
  puts "true"
end
```

or

```
if "test".include? "te" || ("test".include? "fail" )
  puts "true"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if "test".include?("te") || "test".include?("fail")
  puts "true"
end
```